# storage function still erroring

Tags: substrate-node-template

Code:

```rs
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

#[frame_support::pallet]
pub mod pallet {
    use frame_support::pallet_prelude::*;
    use frame_system::pallet_prelude::*;
    use sp_std::vec::Vec;

    #[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
        type RuntimeEvent: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::RuntimeEvent>;
    }
    

    

    #[pallet::event]   
    #[pallet::generate_deposit(pub(super) fn deposit_event)]
    pub enum Event<T: Config> {
        ClaimCreated(T::AccountId, Vec<u8>),
        ClaimRevoked(T::AccountId, Vec<u8>),
    }

    #[pallet::error]   
    pub enum Error<T> {
        ProofAlreadyClaimed,
        NoSuchProof,
        NotProofOwner,
    }

    #[pallet::pallet]
    #[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
    pub struct Pallet<T>(_);

    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn proofs)]
    pub type Proofs<T: Config> = StorageMap<
        _,
        Blake2_128Concat,
        Vec<u8>,
        (T::AccountId, T::BlockNumber),
        ValueQuery,
    >;
    

    
    #[pallet::hooks]
    impl<T: Config> Hooks<BlockNumberFor<T>> for Pallet<T> {}

    #[pallet::call]   // <-- Step 6. code block will replace this.
    impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
        #[pallet::weight(1_000)] 
        pub fn create_claim(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            proof: Vec<u8>,
        ) -> DispatchResult {
            // Check that the extrinsic was signed and get the signer.
            // This function will return an error if the extrinsic is not signed.
            // https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/origins
            let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;

            // Verify that the specified proof has not already been claimed.
            ensure!(!Proofs::<T>::contains_key(&proof), Error::<T>::ProofAlreadyClaimed);

            // Get the block number from the FRAME System module.
            let current_block = <frame_system::Pallet<T>>::block_number();

            // Store the proof with the sender and block number.
            Proofs::<T>::insert(&proof, (&sender, current_block));

            // Emit an event that the claim was created.
            Self::deposit_event(Event::ClaimCreated(sender, proof));

            Ok(())
        }

        #[pallet::weight(10_000)]
        pub fn revoke_claim(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            proof: Vec<u8>,
        ) -> DispatchResult {
            let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;

            ensure!(Proofs::<T>::contains_key(&proof), Error::<T>::NoSuchProof);

            let (owner, _) = Proofs::<T>::get(&proof);

            ensure!(sender == owner, Error::<T>::NotProofOwner);

            Proofs::<T>::remove(&proof);

            Self::deposit_event(Event::ClaimRevoked(sender, proof));

            Ok(())
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```rs
  --- stderr
     Compiling pallet-template v4.0.0-dev 
  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `sp_std`
    |
  7 |     use sp_std::vec::Vec;
    |         ^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `sp_std`

  warning: use of deprecated struct `pallet::_::Store`: 
                   Use of `#[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]` will be removed after July 2023.
                   Check https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13535 for more details.
     |
  32 |     #[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
     |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = note: `#[warn(deprecated)]` on by default

  warning: use of deprecated constant `pallet::warnings::ImplicitCallIndex_0::_w`: 
                   It is deprecated to use implicit call indices.
                   Please instead ensure that all calls have a `pallet::call_index` attribute or put the pallet into `dev` mode.
           
                   For more info see:
                       <https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12891>
                       <https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11381>
     |
  53 |         pub fn create_claim(
     |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^

  warning: use of deprecated constant `pallet::warnings::ImplicitCallIndex_1::_w`: 
                   It is deprecated to use implicit call indices.
                   Please instead ensure that all calls have a `pallet::call_index` attribute or put the pallet into `dev` mode.
           
                   For more info see:
                       <https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12891>
                       <https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11381>
     |
  78 |         pub fn revoke_claim(
     |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^

  warning: use of deprecated constant `pallet::warnings::ConstantWeight_0::_w`: 
                   It is deprecated to use hard-coded constant as call weight.
                   Please instead benchmark all calls or put the pallet into `dev` mode.
           
                   For more info see:
                       <https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13798>
     |
  52 |         #[pallet::weight(1_000)] 
     |                          ^^^^^

  warning: use of deprecated constant `pallet::warnings::ConstantWeight_1::_w`: 
                   It is deprecated to use hard-coded constant as call weight.
                   Please instead benchmark all calls or put the pallet into `dev` mode.
           
                   For more info see:
                       <https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13798>
     |
  77 |         #[pallet::weight(10_000)]
     |                          ^^^^^^

  error[E0220]: associated type `BlockNumber` not found for `T`
     |
  41 |         (T::AccountId, T::BlockNumber),
     |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^ there is an associated type `BlockNumber` in the trait `BlockNumberProvider`
     |
  help: consider further restricting this bound
     |
  37 |     pub type Proofs<T: Config + BlockNumberProvider> = StorageMap<
     |                               +++++++++++++++++++++

  error[E0220]: associated type `BlockNumber` not found for `T`
     |
  41 |         (T::AccountId, T::BlockNumber),
     |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^ there is an associated type `BlockNumber` in the trait `BlockNumberProvider`
     |
  help: consider further restricting this bound
     |
  35 |     #[pallet::storage + BlockNumberProvider]
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/41ad4a6c9d712ac4b6e16e79a8b3837af8234f46/pallets/template/src/lib.rs to update your code.

It seems you're updating Substrate from a pretty old version. There have been numerous syntax changes.

Comment: Do you know the specific changes I need to make. Preety new to substrate and it is becoming extremely hard to  figure out the changes.

Comment: Your pallet is pretty simple.
Just put your logic into the template part by part, then everything should work.

Comment: And if you encounter an error after modifying a part. Search that error in this site. For example, `Event` to `RuntimeEvent`, there were already a lot of existing answers.